# Not able to parse HTML content using PHP because of special characters

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to scrape a website by using CURL. So far I have written the following:

Curl class:

```
<?php

class Curl
{       

    public $cookieJar = "";

    public function __construct($cookieJarFile = 'cookies.txt') {
        $this->cookieJar = $cookieJarFile;
    }

    function setup()
    {


        $header = array();
        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] =  "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] =  "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.


        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
        curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    }


    function get($url)
    { 
        $this->curl = curl_init($url);
        $this->setup();

        return $this->request();
    }

    function getAll($reg,$str)
    {
        preg_match_all($reg,$str,$matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }

    function postForm($url, $fields, $referer='')
    {
        $this->curl = curl_init($url);
        $this->setup();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        return $this->request();
    }

    function getInfo($info)
    {
        $info = ($info == 'lasturl') ? curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) : curl_getinfo($this->curl, $info);
        return $info;
    }

    function request()
    {
        return curl_exec($this->curl);
    }
}

?>
```

And then I'm calling this curl class in my php file:

```
include_once("curl.php");
$curl = new Curl();
$html = $curl->get("www.somewebsite.com");
$html = htmlentities($html);
//echo $html;
$pattern = htmlentities("<span class=\"review-text\">");
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
echo get_string_between($html, '<span class=\"review-text\">', '<\/span>');
```

Now that I'm trying to get the string between the two strings, I'm getting a blank page. However when I see the html content, I am clearly able to spot the string.

The HTML content is very big and I'm trying search and get the content between the huge file.

I even tried replacing the "<" symbol with "`&lt;`" sign but it does not seem to find the string.

Comment: use htmlspecialchars http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @MohamadAttat: It doesn't seem to work that way either.

Answer (score 1):

'There is a better way to get the value of a html tag, by using the dom.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom -> loadHTML($html);
$dom -> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$spans = getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach($spans as $span){
  if($span -> getAttribute('class') == 'review-text'){ print $span-> nodeValue }
}
```

Or there is another way:

```
$dompath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$review_div = $dompath -> query('//*[@class="review-text"]')->item(0)
$string = $review_div -> nodeValue;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This method gives me a 500 internal server error. Any idea why?

Comment: The 500 error is server-side, it means it is something wrong with the server. I do not think it has anything to do with the php script. Or if your echoing the curl response, it can be that the page your are trying to crawl has the error.